# Spring JMX Mbean not appearing or being registered with jconsole

Tags: spring, tomcat, jmx, spring-jmx

Just trying out a simple Spring JMX application within eclipse on a local tomcat server but can't seem to register the mbeans so they then become available to view within jconsole, within eclipse context:component-scan   does appear to pick up beans i have created however these are not registered. When programmatically registering mbeans it works.

Here is my config xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="mbeanServer" class="java.lang.management.ManagementFactory"
lazy-init="false" factory-method="getPlatformMBeanServer">
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.jmx.beans" />
<context:mbean-export server="mbeanServer" />

</beans>
```

The simple bean i'm trying to register with annotations

```
package com.jmx.beans;

import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedAttribute;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ManagedResource(objectName="bean:name=Hello")
public class Hello{

String message =  null;

@ManagedAttribute(description="get the message")
public String getMessage(){

    return this.message;
}

@ManagedAttribute(description="set the message")
public void setMessage(String Message){

    this.message = Message;

}
}
```

I have also set the tomcat server arguements as follows

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9990
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.hostname="localhost"
```

Any Help on this would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why did you edit your post to remove the `<context:component-scan/>`? That is required to find your `@Component`.

I just tested and all worked fine for me...

```
@Component
@ManagedResource
public class Foo {

    @ManagedAttribute
    public int getIt() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

and

```
<context:mbean-server/>

<context:component-scan base-package="foo" />

<context:mbean-export/>
```

I tried it with your style of MBean server and that worked too.

Comment: removed some of the commented stuff and accidently removed the component-scan as well. thanks, it's still not working am i missing something? different folder structure perhaps?

Comment: Nope - I just added your com.jmx.beans.Hello class to my project and changed the base-package to com.jmx.beans and it shows up just fine. I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging; you should end up with an INFO log "...AnnotationMBeanExporter] Bean with name 'hello' has been autodetected for JMX exposure"

Comment: Thanks but still no joy, i can't see what else i'm missing, there doesn't seem to many complete tutorials around so i may be able to see where i am going wrong. I have a feeling it has to do with my spring jars

Comment: I suggest you take a step back and try deploying the context in a simple main() and see if it shows up in JConsole (eliminate the Tomcat container for now). Turn on DEBUG logging for org.springframework - you'll see lots of useful logging for the process of bean creation (and detection) as well as the JMX export process. If you get it working there, do the same in Tomcat and compare the logs.

Comment: Turns out the code was correct, the folder structure was completely wrong. For anyone else having a similar problem, i created a template project to look at. If you wish to do this in eclipse go to File -> New -> other -> spring -> spring template project (you need a spring plugin for eclipse). From there i was able to work out what my project should look like. Thanks for the help!

Comment: +1 for @Component. For some reason neither [this spring doc](http://static.springsource.com/projects/instrumentation/instrument/html/ch05.html) nor [this one](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html) uses @Component. Once I've added @Component I could see AnnotationMBeanExporter reporting that `Bean with name 'myBean' has been autodetected for JMX exposure`.

Comment: The above comment, which mentions @Component helped me. I was trying to make it work , not sure how I missed the annotation

Answer (score 1):

Old question but still valid.You can use the following vm argument for the Mbean not appearing up issue.

```
-Dspring.jmx.enabled=true
```

Comment: You are relying on Spring Boot's autoconfiguration, while the OP didn't use Spring Boot.

Comment: This solved the issue for me.  I was able to see my mbean when running on my desktop but I had to add that property to be able to see the same mbean in JConsole when the app runs on linux.